# From an array of Car instances how to filter such items by e.g. year and model?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, mapping, es6-class

Hi guys I have pushed a class/object into an array like below:

```
class AllCar  {
  constructor(){
    this.carList=[]
  }
  addCar(newCar){
    this.carList.push(newCar)
  }
}

class Car {
  constructor(name, year, model) {
    this.name = name;
    this.year = year;
    this.model = model;
  }
}

const myCar = new Car("Ford", 2014, "Mustang");
const myCar2 = new Car("Toyota", 2014, "Vios");
const myCar3 = new Car("Honda", 2014, "City");
console.log(myCar)
console.log(myCar.model)
const myCars= new AllCar()
myCars.addCar(myCar)
myCars.addCar(myCar2)
myCars.addCar(myCar3)
console.log(myCars.carList)
```

before the class/object went into the array. I am able to output console.log(myCar.model) for the model only. After the push into the array, I am not able to select from the property but I can only show the whole list([Car {...}, Car {...}, Car {...}]).
How do I filter the carList (e.g. filter the year "2014") and show the output model only (["Mustang","Vios","City"]) or name only["Ford","Toyota","Honda"] without the key.

Comment: This has nothing to do with OOP. You're basically just asking 1) how to filter an array in JavaScript; and 2) how to map an array of objects to an array of some property of those objects. Both of these questions have been extensively answered on Stack Overflow.

Comment: In addition to all the other comments and answers there is no need for an additional `AllCar` class. Especially how it(s sole instance) gets used within the example code, such a class just does not make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

Use array methods

```js
class AllCar  {
  constructor(){
    this.carList=[]
  }
  addCar(newCar){
    this.carList.push(newCar)
  }
}

class Car {
  constructor(name, year, model) {
    this.name = name;
    this.year = year;
    this.model = model;
  }
}

const myCar = new Car("Ford", 2014, "Mustang");
const myCar2 = new Car("Toyota", 2014, "Vios");
const myCar3 = new Car("Honda", 2014, "City");
const myCars= new AllCar()
myCars.addCar(myCar)
myCars.addCar(myCar2)
myCars.addCar(myCar3)
console.log(myCars.carList.filter(car => car.year === 2014).map(car => car.model))
```

Comment: Ooo, thanks. Previously I tried to use filter but used in a wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

```
// You can use the filter method present in javascript for arrays.

// **** YOUR CODE START ****
class AllCar {
  constructor() {
    this.carList = [];
  }
  addCar(newCar) {
    this.carList.push(newCar);
  }
}

class Car {
  constructor(name, year, model) {
    this.name = name;
    this.year = year;
    this.model = model;
  }
}

const myCar = new Car("Ford", 2014, "Mustang");
const myCar2 = new Car("Toyota", 2013, "Vios");
const myCar3 = new Car("Honda", 2011, "City");
console.log(myCar);
console.log(myCar.model);
const myCars = new AllCar();
myCars.addCar(myCar);
myCars.addCar(myCar2);
myCars.addCar(myCar3);
console.log(myCars);

// ****YOUR CODE END ****

// *** WHAT YOU CAN DO START ****

const filterCar = (UserYear) => {
  let filteredCar = myCars.carList.filter((item) => item.year === UserYear);
  console.log(filteredCar);
};
filterCar(2014);

// *** WHAT YOU CAN DO END ****
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
[…]
const myCars= new AllCar()
myCars.addCar(myCar)
myCars.addCar(myCar2)
myCars.addCar(myCar3)

console.log(myCars.carList.filter(car => car.year === 2014)); // lists only cars made in 2014

console.log(myCars.carList.map(car => car.model)); // Show only model names

console.log(myCars.carList.filter(car => car.year === 2014).map(car => car.model)); // you can chain them!
```

Comment: Ooo, thanks for the explanation. Previously I tried to use filter but used in a wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

From my above comment ...

> *"In addition to all the other comments and answers there is no need for an additional `AllCar` class. Especially how it(s sole instance) gets used within the example code, such a class just does not make any sense. "*

A possible way of tracking `Car` instances could look similar to the next provided code example ...

```js
const Car = (() => {

  // module scope / (local) function scope.
  const carList = [];

  // export.
  return class Car {
    constructor(name = '', year = null, model = '' ) {
      Object.assign(this, { name, year, model });
      carList.push(this);
      return this;
    }
    deregister() {
      const idx = carList
        .findIndex(car => (car === this));

      if (idx >= 0) {
        const dump = carList.splice(idx, 1);

        Reflect.deleteProperty(dump[0], 'name');
        Reflect.deleteProperty(dump[0], 'year');
        Reflect.deleteProperty(dump[0], 'model');
        // Reflect.deleteProperty(dump, '0');

        dump.length = 0;
      }
    }
    static getInstances() {
      // return just a shallow copy
      // of the `Car` instances array.
      return [...carList];
    }
  };
})();

new Car("Ford", 2014, "Mustang");
new Car("Toyota", 2015, "Vios");
new Car("Honda", 2014, "City");

console.log(
  Car
    .getInstances()
    .filter(({ year }) => year === 2014)
    .map(({ model }) => model)
);
const [ myCar, myCar2, myCar3 ] = Car.getInstances();

console.log({
  carList: Car.getInstances(),
  myCar,
  myCar2,
  myCar3,
});

myCar2.deregister();
myCar.deregister();

console.log({
  carList: Car.getInstances(),
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```